# How to design an icon wrapper in php

Tags: font-awesome, wrapper

We are looking at beginning to use font awesome in our php application but would like to attempt to build some type of wrapper for icons so that if in a few years we decide to use some other icon pack we don't have to go through and refactor everything.

Is there anyone who has accomplished something like this? Or anyone that has any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS? Then you can have classes, and update the classes to specific fonts when you decide to change, and all that have that class will get updated

```
.icon-twitter::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands"; 
    content: "\f099";
 }
```

Could be changed to:

```
 .icon-twitter::before {
    font-family: "New Font Library"; 
    content: "\f0000"; //New font library content for the icon you want.
 }
```